# Why can I reference a variable not yet defined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When creating the function `foo` here, I reference a variable `fromTheFuture` the hasn't been declared yet. This **actually works** as expected, but **why**? Is it considered dangerous or bad practice?

```
var foo = function(x) {
  return fromTheFuture * x;
};

var fromTheFuture = 5;

console.log(foo(10));
```

I can see this being very convenient though, if you have several functions that wants use each other in a cycle fashion - without having to declare them all with `var` in the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time `foo` is called, `fromTheFuture` is defined. More accurately, due to hoisting, your code is essentially:

```
var foo, fromTheFuture;
foo = function(x) {return fromTheFuture*x;};
fromTheFuture = 5;
console.log(foo(10));
```

If you were to call `foo(10)` before `fromTheFuture=5`, you would get `NaN`.

Comment: **Defined**, yes, but how would it know that it would be **declared** (and defined) *in the future* at some time? When rewritten, however, with this `hoisting` effect, it makes sense. How reliable is hoisting? Does it work in every browser? Does it always work?

Comment: The Javascript code is fully analyzed and processed before anything runs.  Many systems even compile it down to a form of byte code.  But to answer your question, variable declaration hoisting is part of the language and 100% reliable.  However, many people think it is good practice to manually put the declarations in early to avoid confusion /and/ to group the declarations together for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the entire script is **processed** first, the variables added to the "data store" and only then the execution is performed.

However, this is not encouraged as it makes the code hard to read. If you want to know more about javascript code quality, check out [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/). It's a sort of FxCop for js. Try copy-pasting your code in there.

Answer (score 1):

the reasone behined it in javascript it define all varible first and then start initializing and then after if somewhere it need its intialization point it try intializized called one first